# ASP.NET MVC3: Force controller to use date format dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Basically, my datepicker uses UK format of `dd/mm/yyyy`. But when I submit the form, ASP.net is clearly using US format.
(will only accept days if less than 12, i.e. thinks it is the month.)

```
 public ActionResult TimeTable(DateTime ViewDate)
```

Is there a way to force it to recognise a certain way?

Strangely though, other methods of insert seem to recognise the correct format.

"The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter `ViewDate` of non-nullable type `System.DateTime` for method `System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(System.DateTime)` in `Mysite.Controllers.RoomBookingsController`. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter."

Comment: Note: you also need to change the unobtrusive javascript, if you wish to save using MVC3. Else it wont even let you post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12053022/mvc-datetime-validation-uk-date-format

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have a read of [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/melvynharbour/archive/2008/11/21/mvc-modelbinder-and-localization.aspx). It gives a good explanation of what's happening and why it works as it does.

I'm in the situation where I know everyone using the site is in the UK so I can safely override the default `DateTime` model binder:

```
public class DateTimeModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var date = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName).AttemptedValue;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(date))
            return null;

        bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(bindingContext.ModelName, bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName));
        try
        {
            return DateTime.Parse(date);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName, String.Format("\"{0}\" is invalid.", bindingContext.ModelName));
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Reading through the provided, it makes more sense as to the different situations. This post immediately calls a view of which the formats vary. Where as the other posts store to the DB. and hence are recognised properly.

Comment: Ok, So where would I place this code /  How would I reference it, to be used. Cheers

Comment: I have the code above in it's own file in a Binders directory. You then need to register the binder in `Application_Start()` with something like `ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(DateTime), new DateTimeModelBinder())`

Comment: Your code is constantly inversing the datetime. so it is UK then US then UK etc etc etc. Well - It doesnt fix the display problem. There is clearly a clash in US and UK still being used, causing weird effects. im using `addday(1)` and it keeps inverting.

Comment: Finally I can add comments. Consider using DateTime.TryParseExact(), you can specify your DateTime format there ("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"

Comment: While it feels a bit weird to overwrite this, it does work, With a little modification to parse it with a culture format. Why did no one edit this answer yet?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use custom ModelBinder for your DateTime. I had that same problem as you.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting the Current Culture as en-GB?

```
protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
{
     base.Initialize(requestContext);

     CultureInfo cultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB");

     Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
     Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;                    
 }
```

Comment: Where would this go? Global.asax.cs?

Comment: There are several places, my example is overriding the Controller initialize method, but you can put it in View.InitializeCulture or in Global.asax too. see here; http://forums.asp.net/p/1521130/3656712.aspx

Comment: This won't work unless the `DateTime` is coming from the form collection. If it's coming from the query string or route data the culture is ignored.

Comment: I put it at the top of my booking controller, but it still does the same thing. :(

Comment: Definitely prefer to add this in Application_BeginRequest() in Global.asax.cs

Answer (score 2):

> Basically, my datepicker uses UK format of dd/mm/yyyy

Beginner mistake. It should use whatever format the browser is set to. The problem is not a format, but different formats between client and server. The server should emit code that formats the date according to the negotiated locale which the server then also uses to parse it.

> But when I submit the form, ASP.NET is clearly using US format.

Nope. This is saying that when I take a spice it always is salt and then you always take salt. Your Server accepts the currently negotiated culture which - unless you modify settings - is negotiated between client and server. Check the threads current culture when it should do the parsing to see what it is set for.

Comment: Ok, so if datetimepicker uses the Browser set options, it would still come in to asp.net code in the actual represented datetime regardless of datetimepickers format?

Comment: Depends how you code it. Can also come as string from a badly written datetime picker. You say "MY datetime picker". Fix it ;)

Comment: Ouch - likely totally ignorant on the settings negotiated with the server. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870605/jquery-datetime-picker-date-format-issue to see how oyu have to initialize it in the page ;) Basically tell it to use the negotiated formatting. THen they match.

Comment: I've currently got jquery datetimepicker overridden to use UK format. My PC is in UK format, but it still reads as US in post to C# code. Even with the below override. :( Im still at a loss on how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it:

- globally (in global.asax under Application_Start() ):

  ```
  ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(DateTime), new DateTimeModelBinder());
  ```
- for a method:

  ```
      public ActionResult TimeTable([Binder(typeof(DateTimeModelBinder)]DateTime ViewDate)
  ```
- for a custom model class - ah no, no posibility cause you use struct DateTime ;-)

Ah, sorry I couldn't add a comment to Adams post - it's based on his code.

Answer (score 0):

From my BindigTools for bindning  DateTime? (Nullable), based on some book sample - Pro MVC3

```
    public static DateTime? GetValueNDateTime(ModelBindingContext context, string searchPrefix, string key, string format)
    {
        ValueProviderResult vpr = context.ValueProvider.GetValue(searchPrefix + key);
        DateTime outVal;
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(vpr.AttemptedValue, format, null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out outVal))
        {
            return outVal;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

It uses parsing exact so you shouldn't have any problem with parsed dates.