# future dates raise error jquery ui datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have that script for jquery ui datepicker

```
var date = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 1));


$('.date').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    defaultDate: date,
    minDate: Date.parse("1900-01-01"),
    maxDate: Date.parse("2100-01-01"),
});
```

and in my view I have:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EndDate, new { @class = "date" })
```

It works ok for yesterday and previous dates, but raises error if i'll select today or higher date

[image]

what's wrong?

**EDIT**

**GOT IT**
It's about my format. I want it to be dd-mm-yy but when I select for example 15-05-2016 it says that there isn't 15 month in year. How can I solve that?

Comment: I think `new Date()` is taking your system date format.

Comment: @AkashAmin `Date` objects don't have any inherent format. @George Are you sure that is the problem? The picture shows *The EndDate field is required.*

Comment: @4castle yes if i choose 5-5-2016 it works but for 12+ doesn't

Comment: @4castle I debug it and 12-5-2016 I got 12-may-2016 but for 13-05-16 raised error end date is required

Comment: @4castle You may be right they don't have inherent format, but while setting the value `defaultDate: date` It will take the date in whatever format it is given.

Comment: @George why dont you try to set the defualt date manually to the date you are getting error with.

Comment: @AkashAmin can you give me an example how can I do that? I'm a  bit confused

Comment: @George I was talking about setting the `defaultDate=13-05-16`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I get unobtrusive validation needs to be overloaded for different format [this answer helped me.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12053022/mvc-datetime-validation-uk-date-format)

```
$.validator.addMethod('date',
function (value, element) {
    if (this.optional(element)) {
        return true;
    }

    var ok = true;
    try {
        $.datepicker.parseDate('dd-mm-yy', value);
    }
    catch (err) {
        ok = false;
    }
    return ok;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`Date.parse()` returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970 for a date string, and `minDate` and `maxDate` can accept a number, but it is used in this way:

> **Number**: A number of days from today. For example `2` represents two days from today and `-1` represents yesterday

Therefore, the validation is expecting you to enter a date that is between **`2208988800000` days in the past and `4102444800000` days in the future**. These dates are incredibly distant, and are too large for a `Date` to handle.

To fix it, use `new Date()` instead.

```
$('.date').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    defaultDate: -1,
    minDate: new Date("1900-01-01"),
    maxDate: new Date("2100-01-01")
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pvynwfs1/1/)

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle that shows the problem? Here's one to get you started: [JSFiddle with jQuery UI](https://jsfiddle.net/soeaz063/)

Comment: I've made it but here can't submit any form. https://jsfiddle.net/86bpLj5s/ my code is that but using that i can't show any error

Comment: Ok, well I'm not much help if the problem isn't reproducible. Let me know if you figure something out.

Comment: it was fault of unobtrusive validation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12053022/mvc-datetime-validation-uk-date-format this helped

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it myself, but it may solve this problem.

change above date format like this

```
dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
```

or simply remove that line because default dateFormat is `mm/dd/yy`

Comment: in my country our format is dd-mm-yy that's why i want that format