# Invalid date error for the future dates in datepicker

Tags: php, codeigniter, date, datepicker, codeigniter-3

Data from database is correct and date format modification also work correctly, while printing it in datepicker input field ,it gives me `invalid date error` for future date but works fine for present and past date

Here is datepicker textbox

```
<input type="text" name="meeting_date" value="<?php print_r(date('d-m-Y',strtotime($edit[0]['meeting_date']))); ?>" class="form-control has-feedback-left" id="single_cal4" aria-describedby="inputSuccess2Status3">
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: and what is that error?

Comment: "invalid date" printed in textbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

*Make sure date format for datepicker is correct try with `m-d-Y` or `Y-m-d`*

and use `echo` instead of `print_r` or use shorthand php syntax like this :

```
<input type="text" 
       value="<?=date('m-d-Y',strtotime($edit[0]['meeting_date'])); ?>" 
       name="meeting_date"  
       class="form-control has-feedback-left" 
       id="single_cal4" aria-describedby="inputSuccess2Status3">
```

Comment: can u show your present date format which is working for you or try with `m-d-Y` or `Y-m-d`

Comment: problem is with date format try with `m-d-Y` or `Y-m-d`

Comment: pleasure is mine , happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Please always share your error code. Anyways

Solution:
Use different date format.
Here is a solution on StackOverflow. I hope it helps.

[Solutions 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12053022/mvc-datetime-validation-uk-date-format)

[Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37247370/future-dates-raise-error-jquery-ui-datepicker)