# Getting an error "Required field must be a date"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm doing a project for school, an MVC application. Since the professor provides us with sample project files, I didn't bother writing my own validation code but the code looks okay to me. Here it is: (ignore the commented lines)

http://prntscr.com/c8gey6

However, when I enter the date in application, I get this:

http://prnt.sc/c8gdpk

What's wrong with the date format I'm entering?

Comment: Is it the full-stop at the end, or does it still complain without that?

Comment: It still shows the error

Comment: Check this post it seems that a few people may be having that issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12053022/mvc-datetime-validation-uk-date-format