# How to use jquery globalize with jquery validate unobtrusive in mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, date, jquery-validate, globalization, unobtrusive-validation

i use mvc 5 but the jquery validate unobtrusive validates the date as MM/dd/yyyy and when i searched how to make it validates dd/MM/yyyy

i found jquery globalize to achieve this but i dont find any examples for the current version Globalize v1.1.2

All the examples i found is for the versions less than 1.x

The view

```html
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date, "dd/MM/yyyy", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

The metadata specified the date to be dd/MM/yyyy

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = " الحقل مطلوب ")]
    [DisplayName("تاريخ ")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

although that jquery validate unobtrusive validates the date as MM/dd/yyyy

[image]

Comment: You need to include the code, not images of it

Comment: the question edited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this problem before, you will need to overload jquery unobtrusive validation  date validation method ([as answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14081487/3222478)), for it to know entered value is a date. By doing this you wont need to use jquery globalize.

**code**

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $.validator.addMethod('date',
    function (value, element) {
        if (this.optional(element)) {
            return true;
        }

        var ok = true;
        try {
            $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', value);
        }
        catch (err) {
            ok = false;
        }
        return ok;
    });
```

Otherwise if you set your application to use local culture you could then use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28754485/3222478)

```
 jQuery(function ($) {
        $.validator.addMethod('date', function (value, element) {
        var d = new Date();
        return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(d.toLocaleDateString(value)));
        });
     });
```

Comment: Very nice, especially if you don't want to add several script files just to achieve this. Thank you :)