# ServiceStack UK Date Binding on HTTP POST

Tags: c#, servicestack, servicestack-razor

I am using a mono self hosted servicestack application with the ServiceStack.Razor rendering. In the application the user enters into a form a UK date (dd/mm/yyyy) but this is converted to a US date (mm/dd/yyyy) on a HTTP POST.

In a normal MVC application I would do this using model binding as shown here [ASP.NET MVC3: Force controller to use date format dd/mm/yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474768/asp-net-mvc3-force-controller-to-use-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy)

How do you do this in ServiceStack as I could not find anything about it.

Comment: If you know how it is going to be delivered, can't you just convert it back to your desired format in your service?  Also, check this out https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Text.Tests/JsonTests/JsonDateTimeTests.cs

Comment: It would not work as I would get invalid dates when the day goes over 12 as it would think the month in US dates was not valid. I could use a string but that would defeat the point of using binding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [custom serializers/deserializers](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text#custom-serialization-routines) to globally control the serialization and deserialization of DateTime values:

In your AppHost:

```
using ServiceStack.Text;

JsConfig<DateTime>.SerializeFn = SerializeAsUKDate;
// Also, if you need to support nullable DateTimes:
JsConfig<DateTime?>.SerializeFn = SerializeAsNullableUKDate;

public static string SerializeAsUKDate(DateTime value)
{
    // or whatever you prefer to specify the format/culture
    return value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
}

public static string SerializeAsNullableUKDate(DateTime? value)
{
    return value.HasValue ? SerializeAsUKDate(value.Value) : null;
}
```

You may or may not need to specify `DeSerializeFn` to ensure that dates are parsed correctly. The ServiceStack.Text date deserializer is pretty robust.

```
JsConfig<DateTime>.DeSerializeFn = DeSerializeAsUKDate;

public static DateTime DeSerializeAsUKDate(string value)
{
    // date parsing logic here
    // ServiceStack.Text.Common.DateTimeSerializer has some helper methods you may want to leverage
}
```