# Formatting jquery.datetimepicker textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime, datetimepicker

I'm using the jquery plugin datetimepicker. When I select a date, the format is yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm. I'd like to change it to mm/dd/yy hh:mm.

This solution, seen in other posts, does not seem to work (doesn't affect format): [Jquery Datetime picker Date format Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870605/jquery-datetime-picker-date-format-issue)

Any ideas how to change this?

I'm using jQuery DateTimePicker plugin v2.4.5 http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

Answer (score 2):

The option is "format", not "dateFormat":

```
jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'm/d/Y H:i'
});
```